# How do I link to wechat from a web to open app

Tags: hyperlink, deep-linking, wechat

Example:deep link:    *weixin://dl/chat?{toID}*
{toID} is  WeChat ID
But it not true. 
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: deep tag means something else than deep-linking

Comment: you can use just `<a href="weixin://">link</a>` to make a link which jumps to WeChat App.

Comment: @shaochuancs hi I want to open some any other URL in app(not only open app) but giving error. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51931400/wechat-deeplink-is-not-opening-properly-in-app-from-mobile-browser