# Wechat deeplink is not opening properly in app from mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, deep-linking, url-scheme, wechat

I am basically trying to open wechat app from mobile web browser for payment. But any of the Deeplink url scheme I tried like these:

https://spacekid.me/weixin-url-schemes/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35576003/3326275

However **all of them** giving me following error though application opens:

[image: error]
I tried to use any of the urls, all of them are giving me same error as above. I want to open payment URL in web app. Leave that alone, any of the links.
Any one knows :

1. Why am I facing error, is there any way to open any deeplink without error.
2. How to open payment URL from browser to app so he can pay via app? Note that I able to generate business payment link such as weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=psg07It , but how to open in app without facing error as in image above.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Crashalot Nope, did you have the same issue ?

Comment: Yes, it works inconsistently using this URL scheme: weixin://dl/profile/wechatid. But it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: @Crashalot I wish they had Proper documentation. Its worst documentation I came across.